# Wiki Engine in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wiki

I've been using [vimwiki](http://code.google.com/p/vimwiki/) for a while now, and I'm quite liking it. However, I spend most of my time in Visual Studio. I'd therefore like to find a personal file-based wiki that works inside Visual Studio. It should be file-based so that the pages live with my project and I can keep them in the same version control repository (Mercurial, in my case, if it makes a difference).

Comment: Don't you want to open any Wiki page within built-in VS browser?

Comment: Using the built-in browser would work, provided that it's tied to the project -- that is: opening the solution would need to start some kind of lightweight web server or something. Finding the URL again is also a must.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Wiki on a Stick](http://stickwiki.sourceforge.net/) or [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/)?

By using a file based wiki, you could check your wiki into source control alongside your code.

You could also view it in VS with the integrated web browser. If you can use relative file:/// urls, you could actually link to your wiki from comments in your code without ever leaving Visual Studio.

Comment: TiddlyWiki doesn't work in the VS browser: It's not possible to save your changes. :(

Comment: Bummer. Maybe swapping out the [browser in VS](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToChangeTheDefaultBrowserInVisualStudioProgrammaticallyWithPowerShellAndPossiblyPokeYourselfInTheEye.aspx) would work?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use Markdown files as docs in your source repository and wire up MSBuild/NAnt/NRake/whatever to run [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) to spit out html docs.

Or, if you hosted your project on GitHub, you'd get this for free.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you would probably find some success with a Markdown based wiki (such as the Jekyll site publishing supported by GitHub).

A good Visual Studio Markdown editor is available from the prolific Mads Kristensen:

- https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaab33c3-437b-4918-8354-872dfe5d1bfe
- https://github.com/madskristensen/MarkdownEditor